# Should QWidget::geometry().topLeft() return QPoint(0, 0) If its frameless and has no parent?

Tags: qt, qwidget

Should `QWidget::geometry().topLeft()` always return `QPoint(0, 0)` If its framelees and has no `parent` ?

Answer (score 0):

If it has no parent then it should return its global position (its position relative to the desktop)

Comment: That's a slightly ambiguous question; but if your widget has no parent, then `widget.mapToGlobal(widget.pos())` would be the same as `widget.pos()`